# go - redirect stderr to file AND to stdout

Tags: file, go, stream, stdout, stderr

I would like to redirect `stderr`to a file AND to `stdout`.

I know how  redirect `stderr` to file using `dup2` :
`err := syscall.Dup2(int(fatal_logfile.Fd()), int(os.Stderr.Fd()))`

But then I don't see how can redirect this another time to `stdout`. Like "copying" one stream-source to two differents streams.

Just a note, this functionality is called when the app starts and used to redirect `stderr` when, for example, a `panic` occurs. Then I cannot use `recover` in this case (even because I am running lots of goroutines).

Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

---

Another working solution is to use `pipes` and `tee` when calling the binary, but is possible to have the same behavior/logic defined inside the app? I would like that it runs in this way as default.

`./app_bin 2> >(tee -a fatal.log)`

Comment: I think it might be better to handle this outside the applications, redirecting stderr as needed. You can probably do this with some pipes and a copy, but you now have a chance to lose stderr output rather than having a single un-buffered stream.

Comment: correct @JimB - I have just updated my question including the resolution of redirecting `stderr` when running the binary. Probably a naïve question, but can I "import" the same logic in the app? I would like that it runs in this way as default

Comment: It's always going to be more reliable to do this outside of your program. If the goal is to capture the output in case of a crash, there's a chance that the function doing the `tee` inside your program may not get the data out before the process exits.

Comment: thanks @JimB for the inputs, I guess that I'll follow your suggestion: apply the redirection outside the application. I will probably include this directly in the `system.d` scripts.

Answer (score 0):

```
writer := io.MultiWriter(os.Stdout, os.Stderr)
```

Whatever it's written to `writer` will write to `os.Stdout` and `os.Stderr`.

Comment: Why the negative 1.  That seems like a viable solution?

Comment: The question is asking for stderr writes to be redirected and duplicated to an os.File and os.Stdout. This creates a separate io.Writer that tees output to os.Stdout and os.Stderr, but doesn't redirect os.Stderr at all.